# UserBot с помощью pyrogram

Tags: python

Прошу Вас подсказать, как сделать, чтоб при вводе допустим "//" в начале сообщения, все сообщение становилось курсивом и жирным.

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client("my_account")

@app.on_message(filters.command("", prefixes="//") & filters.me)
def type(_, msg):
    orig_text = msg.text.input()
    if msg.find(r'//') !=-1:
        msg = '<b>' + msg[2::] + '<b>'
app.run()
```

Я не понимаю, почему не работает.

```
'Str' object has no attribute 'input'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\dispatcher.py", line 219, in handler_worker
    await self.loop.run_in_executor(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\UserBot\main.py", line 7, in type
    orig_text = msg.text.input()
AttributeError: 'Str' object has no attribute 'input'
```

Comment: При вводе куда? А так, телеграм поддерживает parse mode html, соответственно можно просто обернуть в теги <b>text</b>

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то User bot работает от имени самого пользователя. 
При отправке в любой чат, любого сообщения, если я в начале текста введу // то все сообщение становится курсивом и выделяется жирным шрифтом. Для чего это нужно? Чтоб сократить время тыкания мышки по выбору интересующего меня вида шрифта

Comment: Ну допустим вводите вы сообщение `msg = input()` далее `if msg.find(r'//') != -1: msg = '<b>' + msg[2::] + '</b>`

Comment: from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait

app = Client("my_account")

@app.on_message(filters.command("", prefixes="//") & filters.me)
def type(_, msg):
    orig_text = msg.text.input("//")
    if msg.find(r'//') !=-1:
        msg = '<b>' + msg[2::] + '<b>'
app.run()

Я не понимаю, почему не работает(

Comment: Обновите код вопроса, читать невозможно

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client("my_account")

@app.on_message(filters.command("", prefixes="//") & filters.me)
def type(_, msg):
    orig_text = msg.text
    if orig_text.find(r'//') != -1:
        orig_text = '<b>' + orig_text[2::] + '<b>'
app.run()
```